# two pytorch DistributedSampler same seeds different shuffling multiple GPU-s

Tags: pytorch, gpu, distributed-computing, shuffle, pytorch-dataloader

I am trying to load two version (original and principal component pursuit (PCP) cleaned version) of the very same image data set for training a modell using pytorch on a multiple GPUs remote machine.

I would like to ensure the same shuffling order for both the original and the PCP cleaned data. To achieve this, I use `torch.utils.data.DistributedSampler(datasetPCP, shuffle=True, seed=42)` and `torch.utils.data.DistributedSampler(dataset, shuffle=True, seed=42)` samplers to pass these to the dataloaders for train my modell on 3 GPUs are present on the remote machine I use.

As far as I understood the same seed of the two sampler should ensure the exact same shuffling of the loaded data. However this is not the case.

Could anybody point me in the right direction?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

`DistributedSampler` is for distributed data training where we want different data to be sent to different processes so it is not what you need. Regular dataloader will do just fine.

Example:

```py
import torch
from torch.utils.data.dataset import Dataset
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, RandomSampler


class ToyDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, type):
        self.type = type

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return f'{self.type}, {idx}'

    def __len__(self):
        return 10

def get_sampler(dataset, seed=42):
    generator = torch.Generator()
    generator.manual_seed(seed)
    sampler = RandomSampler(dataset, generator=generator)
    return sampler


original_dataset = ToyDataset('original')
pcp_dataset = ToyDataset('pcp')

original_loader = DataLoader(original_dataset, batch_size=2, sampler=get_sampler(original_dataset))
pcp_loader = DataLoader(pcp_dataset, batch_size=2, sampler=get_sampler(pcp_dataset))

for data in original_loader:
    print(data)

for data in pcp_loader:
    print(data)
```

Output:

```
['original, 2', 'original, 6']
['original, 1', 'original, 8']
['original, 4', 'original, 5']
['original, 0', 'original, 9']
['original, 3', 'original, 7']
['pcp, 2', 'pcp, 6']
['pcp, 1', 'pcp, 8']
['pcp, 4', 'pcp, 5']
['pcp, 0', 'pcp, 9']
['pcp, 3', 'pcp, 7']
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's a nice one! However I forget to mention that I use a multi GPU environment. That's why I use `DistributedSampler`. Do you have an alternative solution which would use `DistributedSampler`? It would be really highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Seeting `seed` should suffice if `shuffle=True` and both the dataset are in the same order.

**Sample**

```
class ToyDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = np.arange(20)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return self.data[idx]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

backend = "nccl"
dist.init_process_group(backend=backend)
ddp_rank = int(os.environ["RANK"])
ddp_local_rank = int(os.environ["LOCAL_RANK"])
device = f"cuda:{ddp_local_rank}"

mydataset_1 = ToyDataset()
distributed_sampler_1 = DistributedSampler(dataset=mydataset_1, shuffle=True, seed=123)
dataloader_1 = DataLoader(mydataset_1, batch_size=2, sampler=distributed_sampler_1)

mydataset_2 = ToyDataset()
distributed_sampler_2 = DistributedSampler(dataset=mydataset_2, shuffle=True, seed=123)
dataloader_2 = DataLoader(mydataset_2, batch_size=2, sampler=distributed_sampler_2)

for data1, data2 in zip(dataloader_1, dataloader_2):
    print(f"[{ddp_local_rank}]:: Data1: {data1}, Data2: {data2}")

# for data1 in dataloader_1:
#     print(f"[{ddp_local_rank}]: Data1:  {data1}")

# for data2 in dataloader_2:
#     print(f"[{ddp_local_rank}]: Data2:  {data2}")
    
dist.barrier()
dist.destroy_process_group()
```

Output:

```
[0]:: Data1: tensor([ 2, 15]), Data2: tensor([ 2, 15])
[0]:: Data1: tensor([8, 0]), Data2: tensor([8, 0])
[0]:: Data1: tensor([10,  6]), Data2: tensor([10,  6])
[0]:: Data1: tensor([3]), Data2: tensor([3])
[1]:: Data1: tensor([ 9, 16]), Data2: tensor([ 9, 16])
[1]:: Data1: tensor([ 5, 11]), Data2: tensor([ 5, 11])
[1]:: Data1: tensor([17,  1]), Data2: tensor([17,  1])
[1]:: Data1: tensor([4]), Data2: tensor([4])
[2]:: Data1: tensor([14,  7]), Data2: tensor([14,  7])
[2]:: Data1: tensor([19, 18]), Data2: tensor([19, 18])
[2]:: Data1: tensor([12, 13]), Data2: tensor([12, 13])
[2]:: Data1: tensor([2]), Data2: tensor([2])
```

As you see, each GPU gets same indices from both the datasets.